# triviality of vector bundles with the reduced homology of base space entirely torsion

Tags: algebraic-topology, geometric-topology, vector-bundles, characteristic-classes

Let $\xi$ be an $n$-dimensional vector bundle over a manifold $M$ such that the reduced cohomology 
$\tilde H^*(M;\mathbb{Z})$ is entirely torsion (every element has finite order under addition).

**Question: Prove that there exists an integer $k$ such that the $k$-fold Whitney sum $\xi^{\oplus k}$ is a trivial bundle.**

How to solve this? My attempt: let the classifying map of $\xi$ be
$$
f: M\longrightarrow BO(n).
$$
The induced map on cohomology is
$$
f^*: H^*(BO(n);\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}[w,p]/I\longrightarrow H^*(M;\mathbb{Z})
$$
where $w$ is the Stiefel-Whitney classes and $p$ the Pontrjagin classes? (I am confused about this and did not find proper references). 
By the torsion property, there exists $k$ such that 
$$
w(\xi^{\oplus k})=p(\xi^{\oplus k})=1?
$$
Hence can this imply that $\xi$ is a trivial bundle?

**Question:** if the Stiefel-Whitney classes and Pontrjagin classes of a vector bundle $\eta$ are all trivial, can we obtain that $\eta$ is a trivial bundle?

Comment: For question 2 the answer is negative. Tangent bundle over odd dimensional sphere cannot support nontrivial S-W classes, Euler classes or Pontrjagin classes but most of them are known to be nontrivial by the solution of Hopf invariant one problem.

Comment: This looks a little homework-ish.  What is motivating this question for you?

Comment: For a correct description of the integral cohomology of BO(n), see Brown, Edgar H., Jr. The cohomology of BSOn and BOn with integer coefficients. Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 85 (1982), no. 2, 283–288.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For Question 1 note first that it is important that the base space of the vector bundle be finite-dimensional, as one can see by looking at the canonical line bundle $\gamma$ over ${\mathbb R}P^\infty$ since $w_k(\gamma^{\oplus k})$ is nonzero for all $k\geq 1$, so $\gamma^{\oplus k}$ is not even stably trivial.

On the other hand, for a vector bundle $\xi$ over a base space $X$ which is a finite complex (CW or simplicial) with $H^i(X)$ finite for all $i>0$ then some sum $\xi^{\oplus k}$ is trivial.  This can be proved by an obstruction theory argument.  To begin, $\xi\oplus\xi$ is orientable, hence is trivial over the 1-skeleton of $X$.  Call this bundle $\xi_1$. The obstruction to $\xi_1$ being trivial over the 2-skeleton is $w_2$, at least if $\xi_1$ has dimension at least 3 which can be arranged by replacing the original $\xi$ by $\xi\oplus\xi$. Thus $\xi_2=\xi_1\oplus\xi_1$ will be trivial over the 2-skeleton, and hence also over the 3-skeleton since $\pi_2SO(n)=0$. Note that we haven't used finiteness of any of the groups $H^i(X)$ yet, but instead the finiteness of the first few homotopy groups of $SO(n)$.

Now we proceed inductively. Assume we have a bundle $\xi_n$ which is a sum of copies of $\xi$ and which is trivial over the $n$-skeleton of $X$. Choosing a trivialization over the $n$-skeleton, the obstruction to extending this trivialization over an $(n+1)$-cell is an element of $\pi_nSO(k)$ for $k$ the dimension of $\xi_n$. By obstruction theory, these elements define a cellular $(n+1)$-cochain on $X$ with coefficients in $\pi_nSO(k)$ which is in fact a cocycle. By rechoosing the framing on $n$-cells we can replace this cocycle by any other one in the same cohomology class. In particular, if the cohomology class is zero the bundle $\xi_n$ is trivial over the $(n+1)$-skeleton. This need not be the case initially, but since we assume that the cohomology groups of $X$ are finite, there is some multiple $m$ of the obstruction cocycle which is a coboundary. If we replace $\xi_n$ by $\xi_{n+1}=\xi_n^{\oplus m}$ then it is not hard to check that the obstruction cocycle for $\xi_{n+1}$ becomes zero in cohomology. (There are three ways to add classes in $\pi_n$ of orthogonal groups: (1) the usual addition in $\pi_n$, (2) by using the group structure in the orthogonal groups, and (3) by forming direct sums of matrices. These all coincide, after forming the direct sum in the third case.)  Thus $\xi_{n+1}$ is trivial over the $(n+1)$-skeleton, finishing the induction step when $X$ is a finite complex.  The example with ${\mathbb R}P^\infty$ shows that we may not be able to carry the induction through an infinite number of steps.  If $X$ were finite-dimensional but not finite, one would be able to finish if there were an upper bound on the orders of the elements of $H^i(X)$ for $i>0$.

Answer (score 6):

Question 1: Stable triviality of some multiple $\xi^{\oplus k}$ follows under the given condition on homology from the Atiyah-Hirzebruch spectral sequence for K-theory, which gives that $\tilde{K}(X)$ is torsion.

Question 2: Vanishing of Pontryagin classes of $\xi$ shows stable triviality
of some multiple $\xi^{\oplus k}$: The reason is that stable vector bundles are given by maps to $BO$, and rationally $BO$ is a product of Eilenberg-MacLane spaces of dimension $4j$, corresponding to Pontryagin classes.

Finally for every stably trivial vector bundle $\eta$, some multiple $\eta^{\oplus k}$ is trivial. 
This is a theorem by Lam:
LAM, T.Y. Series summation of stably free modules,
Q J Math (1976) 27 (1): 37-46. doi: 10.1093/qmath/27.1.37

Comment: Thanks. What means stable triviality?